# Ionic - iPhone X statusbar overlays shared header component

Tags: ios, angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

I have seen various similar posts with the problem of the iOS status bar overlaying onto the header of apps.

I haven’t yet seen another post which has the same problem as mine.

I am trying to use a shared header component for certain pages and when I use this, I get the overlaying problem.

I have simplified the code and recreated my problem using the ionic tabs starter template:

[image]
This page is using a shared header component:

```
<ion-header>
  <shared-header title="Home - shared header"></shared-header>
</ion-header>
```

shared-header.component.html

```
<ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>{{title}}</ion-title>
</ion-navbar>
```

shared-header.component.ts

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'shared-header',
    templateUrl: 'shared-header.component.html'
})

export class SharedHeaderComponent {

    @Input('title') title: string;
    constructor() { }
}
```

[image]
This page is **not** using the shared header component:

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>
      About
    </ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>
```

Why would this be happening? Is it because of the extra `<shared-header></shared-header>` tags? If so, what can be done to solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is caused by having the component tag inside the header tag, for some reason this causes the header to render incorrectly.  The solution I used was to use an attribute in the header instead of the component tags.

Inside the component wrap the selector in square brackets to define it be able to use it as an attribute

shared-header.component.ts

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: '[shared-header]',
    templateUrl: 'shared-header.component.html'
})

export class SharedHeaderComponent {

    @Input('title') title: string;
    constructor() { }
}
```

then in the header you can inject the component as an attribute like this

```
<ion-header shared-header title="Home - shared header">
</ion-header>
```

If you want to have access to your component via tags as well as an attribute, you can define multiple selectors

```
@Component({
    selector:'[shared-header], shared-header',
    templateUrl: 'shared-header.component.html'
})
```

Comment: This suggestion worked really well for me, except in the cases where I had other elements in the `ion-header`.  Those elements got dropped with this approach.  It seems like a big hack, but I was able to get past this by adding `<ng-content></ng-content>` at the end of the `shared-header` component template.  Any ideas if that's the best way to make this example work with child elements in `ion-header`?

Answer (score 1):

You can try these below steps

1) Using statusbar cordova plugin, you can set

```
if (this.statusBar) {
   this.statusBar.styleDefault();
   this.statusBar.overlaysWebView(false); 
}
```

2) In index.html, meta tag include  'viewport-fit=cover'

```
 <meta name="viewport" content="viewport-fit=cover, width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, target-densityDpi=device-dpi"/>
```

Can you also try adding padding-top to the header classes

```
header {
    /* ... */
    /* Status bar height on iOS 10 */
    padding-top: 0px;
    /* Status bar height on iOS 11.0 */
    padding-top: constant(safe-area-inset-top);
    /* Status bar height on iOS 11+ */
    padding-top: env(safe-area-inset-top);
}
```

Comment: Hi Suresh, I have already tried both those things. I have viewport-fit=cover in my metadata. If I use statusBar.overlaysWebView(false), I get a gap between the status bar and the header.